# Is possible use prefix or const in a path of the route in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to look how i can put a prefix in a path of route.

```
#routing.yml

app_news:
    path:     /panel/news
    defaults: { _controller: NewsBundle:Default:index }
```

I have some routes like this, if i want change in the future the name of the path, for example

**/admin/news** or **/control/news**

Can i save the prefix in other config yml file and change it when i want?

Comment: this is the routing files of a bundle or of the application?

Comment: you can specify a prefix for all the route inside a bundle as described [here in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html#prefixing-imported-routes)

Comment: in routing files (one bundle one route file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case i have some like this

```
#/app/config/routing.yml
users:
    resource:   "@UsersBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:     /panel/

news:
    resource:   "@NewsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:     /panel/
```

Now, after read the answers and see the others ways i put the prefix, i set the prefix in a var

```
#/app/config/routing.yml
users:
    resource:   "@UsersBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:     %panel_path%

news:
    resource:   "@NewsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:     %panel_path%
```

And i set the %panel_path% var value in

```
#/app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    panel_path: /panel
```

Comment: Altough this will probably work, I strongly recommend you to use Symfony tools instead of self implementations. This will make more maintainable the project.

Answer (score 3):

Put all of your prefixed routes on the same routing file and then add it to your bundle routing using the **resource** and the **prefix** attribute:

```
applications:
     resource: "@NewsBundle/Resources/config/routing_news.yml"
     prefix: /panel
```

Also, if you have your routes on your controller. You can do the same trick using the annotation attribute:

```
applications:
     resource: '@NewsBundle/Controller/NewsController'
     type: annotation
     prefix: /panel
```

Syntaxis changes depending on your Symfony version, so I recommend you to visit the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html#prefixing-imported-routes).